# YOLOv8 custom save directory path

Tags: python, flask, yolo, yolov8

I'm currently working in a project in which I'm using Flask and Yolov8 together.

When I run this code

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("./yolov8n.pt")

results = model.predict(source="../TEST/doggy.jpg", save=True, save_txt=True)
```

the output will be saved in this default directory `/run/detect/`

like

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.9  Python-3.10.8 torch-2.0.0+cpu CPU
Fusing layers... 
YOLOv8n summary: 168 layers, 3151904 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.7 GFLOPs
Results saved to d:\runs\detect\predict4
1 labels saved to d:\runs\detect\predict4\labels
```

and what I want is the `predict` directory number or the entire directory path in a variable.

I tried capturing the path using sys.stdout methods but i want a direct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the directory where the results are saved ([save_dir](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/3fd317edfd2fdd925f919b4e736af5f96aee27e3/ultralytics/yolo/engine/trainer.py#L49)) by modifying two arguments in predict: `project` and `name`

```
results = model.predict(source=xxx, save_txt = True, project="xxx", name="yyy")
```

such that:

```
save_dir=project/name
```